# inkfilepicker does not set public on S3 to images from facebook and instagram only does this for computer uploaded

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm using JavaScript API and pickAndStore function.

My store_options are: 
store_options = {
 location: 'S3',
 access: 'public',
 path: 'photo/source/'
};

My picker options: 
picker_options = {
 extensions: ['.jpg', '.png'],
 services: ['COMPUTER', 'URL', 'FACEBOOK', 'INSTAGRAM', 'FLICKR', 'PICASA', 'DROPBOX'],
 multiple: true
};

When I upload image from my laptop it sets file on S3 public permission. 
When I upload image from Facebook or Instagram it sets file on S3 private permission.

Is it a bug, or Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Ink File Picker. We're working on addressing it and I will update this answer when it is resolved.